# Date Display with elm

Tags: date, elm

How can I display a date with elm? 
I used `toString` but display is too long.

```
let
    date =
        Date.fromTime <| toFloat risk.last_modified
in
    tr []
       [ td [] [ text risk.id ]
       , td [] [ text <| toString date ]
       , td [] [ text risk.title ]
       , td [] [ text risk.admin.comment ]
       , td [] <| badge risk.admin.status
       ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using elm-strftime

You can use [`elm-strftime`](https://github.com/thaterikperson/elm-strftime):

```
elm-package install thaterikperson/elm-strftime
```

And then:

```
import Strftime exposing (format)

showDate : Date -> String
showDate date =
    format "%A %B %d %Y %H:%M" date
```

### Old version using elm-time

Previously I used [`elm-time`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-time/1.0.6/Time-DateTime#fromTimestamp) like that:

```
showDate : DateTime -> String
showDate datetime =
    let
        day =
            DateTime.day datetime

        month =
            DateTime.month datetime

        year =
            DateTime.year datetime

        hour =
            DateTime.hour datetime

        minute =
            DateTime.minute datetime
    in
        (zfill day) ++ "/" ++ (zfill month) ++ "/" ++ (toString year) ++ " " ++ (zfill hour) ++ ":" ++ (zfill minute)


zfill : Int -> String
zfill value =
    let
        string =
            toString value
    in
        if (String.length string) == 1 then
            "0" ++ string
        else
            string
```

You can also use a [ZonedDateTime](https://github.com/imt-timezone-project/timezone-manager/blob/97ffeac7f71d2b281eae0552253776d8815e8749/Main.elm#L286-L304) if you want to display the time in the correct TimeZone.

Comment: You need to `elm-package install elm-time` and then `import Time exposing (DateTime)`

Comment: You can use `elm-strftime` I will add a new answer.